# Am I overexposing my film?

Tags: exposure, aperture, saturation

I’ve just had my first colour film back (kodak gold 200) and lots of the photographs have come out washed-out, low saturation and very white! Lots were taken in sunlight which I tried to account for by changing the aperture but they are such white pictures! I’m using an olympus OM-10, what can I do to prevent this in future? I have lots of kodak gold to use up! In the mean time you’ll find me editing them post-scan 
Thanks!!

edit: just noticed my lens is a bit loose, could that be why?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the pictures

Comment: How are you metering the exposure? This is the most important part, and what film newbies are most likely to neglect, it seems to me. The OM10 has aperture-priority autoexposure, and only offers manual exposure by attaching a special adapter. Do you have this little gizmo? I'd be hesitant to rely 100% on only the camera's built-in meter.

Answer (score 0):

Before I started scanning my own negatives the developers used to do it for me and there were options to have the scanned files back either as 'flat, low contrast images' or 'balanced' - with the first option the digital images were exactly like you described on purpose - suitable for home digital processing. Just a thought!